# Grafana Prometheus bar time interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to get bar chart in Grafana with Prometheus data source. Query is `sum(increase(nginx_http_requests{location="login"}[1d]))`.

Min step = 1d. Everything works, but there is a problem with the last bar. He show values as i understand (for example today 2020-04-17) from 2020-04-17 0:00 to 2020-04-18 0:00. Maybe someone knows is it possible to set bar end date as 2020-04-17 23:59?

Grafana bar example:

[image]